# Slick slider method 'slickPrev' not firing inside bootstrap modal when input gains focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal, slick.js

I am using slick slider and its methods 'slickPrev' and 'slickNext' inside bootstrap modal to slide some content manually.One slide has a form and everything works perfect until form input gains focus and then I am unable to go back to previous slide using the button that triggers 'slickPrev' method.
The problem occurs only on mobile browsers, so far chrome for android.

I've tried to reproduce the problem outside of the modal but it seems the problem occurs only inside of it as you can see in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3x4bum5h/1/ where

```
$('body').on('click','.back-to-content',function(){
        $('.wl-items-swipe').slick('slickPrev');
        $('body').find('.modal-footer .btn-group').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn wl-next-step">Next step <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>');

});
```

only makes the input lose focus otherwise it works as it should when no focus on input.

Comment: The fiddle is working fine for me. try clearing cache maybe?

Comment: @IvanaG.B. No, the cache is not the problem.I keep it clean.Which version of chrome for android do you use? I am using 78.0.3904.108

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found a solution.To make it work I had to remove the buttons that trigger slides from the footer and put them inside the slides.
Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yjex03gf/

```
<div class="wl-content">
     <p id="some-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
         <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>&nbsp;
              <button type="button" class="btn wl-next-step">Next step <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="wl-form">
     <form id="w-items-form">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control wl-email" placeholder="Email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone"  style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px">Phone<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control wl-phone" max="15" placeholder="Phone number"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-wl-submit" style="font-size:14px;">Send <i class="fa fa-send"></i></button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="btn-group">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default back-to-content" style="border-right: 2px solid #ececec;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .modal{
      display:block!important;
      z-index:-1;
    }
    .modal-open .modal{
      z-index:1080;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.